# Dúvida - SQL Server - Usando Union

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

Gente, eu tenho o seguinte Union:

```
select cgc, item, matricula, cota, dataInicio, dataFim 
from [dbo].[cotas] as t1 
where dataFim is null
union
select cgc, item, matricula, cota, dataInicio, dataFim 
from [dbo].[cotas] as t2 
where dataInicio >='01/05/2019' and dataFim<='31/05/2019'

só que eu preciso fazer um resultado final... em que t1.cgc seja diferente de t2.cgc
```

Acontece que quando a dataFim está nula, significa que a cota está ativa. E quando está preenchida, a cota está inativa.
Um funcionário pode ter cotas inativas no CGC que trabalha atualmente, mas não tem como ter cotas ativas em um CGC que já trabalhou e não trabalha mais.
Só que o funcionário (matricula) pode ter trabalhado em mais de um CGC no mesmo mês. Eu preciso, obrigatoriamente, pegar todas as cotas que estiverem ativas. E, pegar, apenas, as inativas que forem de um cgc que ele trabalhou anteriormente.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso com o union? Ou eu deveria fazer de outra forma?
Obrigada.

Comment: Não consegui entender sua explicação, qual o resultado que você espera de retorno? Você quer todas as contas ativas do CGC que seria as contas onde a dataFim is null e contas inativas que tem a dataFim is not null and t2,cgc not in (SELECT t1.cgc from [dbo].[cotas] WHERE where dataFim is null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que você explicou você quer pegar os dados tantos Ativos quanto os inativos,
você pode dar uma subquery nas CGC ativas e realizar um `inner join` nas Inativas, o problema é que ele retornará todas as cotas inativas de um funcionário ativo. Como você precisa que as colunas sejam exibidas sem duplicidade talvez esta opção seja a melhor.

```
select 
    t1.* 
from 
    [dbo].[cotas]
where 
    dataFim is null
UNION
select
    t2.*
from 
    [dbo].[cotas] as t2 
    inner join (
        select cgc, item, matricula, cota, dataInicio, dataFim 
        from [dbo].[cotas]
        where dataFim is null) as t3 on t3.cgc <> t2.cgc 
where t2.dataInicio >='01/05/2019' and t2.dataFim<='31/05/2019'
```

Veja se esta query resolve seu problema.

Comment: Ela quase resolve... só que na verdade é com o t1.cgc<>t2.cgc... mas de qualquer forma, quando faço join... ele duplica todas as colunas e eu precisava dos resultados listados linha a linha, com as colunas individualizadas.... como o que o union faz

Comment: Bom desta forma que você descreve melhor realizar uma query para os não finalizados com uma Union de um segunda query adicionada de um inner join para uma terceira query idêntica a primeira, veja o sql acima ele foi alterado

Comment: Deu certo, era isso mesmo!!! Obrigada!!!!